# GraphDatabaseService.newEmbeddedDataBase(String x) is not working

Tags: neo4j, rdf

While i connect to Neo4j database with the database Factory and graph database service class. It says that newEmbeddedDataBase function with the string is not available any more. I tried even opening through a file and pass that directory but still it is working and says problem in loading the function. Please find my code below and give me feedback.
As a file:

```
File DB_PATH=new File("C:\\Users\\Anurag\\Documents\\Neo4j\\default.graphdb");
    GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
GraphDatabaseService db=dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
```

As a String:

```
Private static final DB_PATH="C:\\Users\\Anurag\\Documents\\Neo4j\\default.graphdb";
    GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
GraphDatabaseService db=dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
```

Comment: which version is it?

Comment: 2.2.3 and i even have 1.8 and 1.4

Comment: what is not working? Please share the full error message/stacktrace. It should work in 2.x with that code. Make sure to not mix up versions in your classpath.